# preventDefault and add/removeClass not working

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

Sorry for the poor title, I have checked all the other preventDefault questions but none of them have provided me with the answer I'm looking for.

Here's what I have (jQuery):

```
    var swiss = $('#post-88 .bookings');

    $("#post-88 .button-book").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swiss.addClass('show');
    });
    $("#post-88 .icon-close").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swiss.removeClass('show');
    });
```

& the HTML:

```
<article id="post-88" class="bg col span-1-3" role="article">
    <div class="feat-still overlap">
        <img width="481" height="330" src="http://domain.com/imgs/img.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="bookings overlay show">

        <form>
            <!-- form stuff here -->
            <a class="icon-close" href="#">Cancel</a>
        </form>
    </div>

    <a class="button-book" href="#" title="Make a reservation">Make a reservation</a>

</article>
```

When clicking `.button-book` the class `show` gets added to `.bookings`, however when clicking on `.icon-close` the page jumps to the top of the page and the class does not get removed – this part of the code just doesn't seem to work.

Am I missing something here..?

**UPDATE:**

I left out part of my code which I now think is causing the problem.
The content to `.bookings` is loaded as follows:

```
var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
var swiss = $('#post-88 .bookings');
swiss.load(root+'/wp-content/themes/PL14-Base/inc/bookings-swiss.php');
```

But I wouldn't have thought this would have an effect on the close button...?

Comment: have you tried using `swiss.addClass('show')` instead of `toggleClass`?

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, it was a result of misunderstanding something. I can't repeat the error you're having, when I put your code into jsfiddle it works fine. (http://jsfiddle.net/WVTxN/3/) Can you post code for the whole page?

Comment: Whoops. It should have read `addClass`- edited the original post

Comment: hmmm. Seeing as this does work in the jsfiddle example I'm wondering if it's not to do with something else. I omitted some part of the code for clarity – the content in `.bookings` is actually being called in via ajax. I wonder if this is the reason the close button is not working. I'll update my post to include this.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this working, but I had to add extra markup :(

If anyone can resolve the original issue without the extra markup I'd be keen to know how.

**Solution**

HTML:

```
<article id="post-88" class="bg col span-1-3" role="article">

    <div class="feat-still overlap">
        <img width="481" height="330" src="http://domain.com/imgs/img.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="bookings overlay">
        <div class="load-form"></div>
        <a class="icon-close" href="#">Cancel</a>
    </div>

    <a class="button-book" href="#" title="Make a reservation">Make a reservation</a>

</article>
```

jQuery:

```
    var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
    var swissContainer = $('#post-88 .bookings');
    var swissForm = $('#post-88 .bookings .load-form');
    var swissClose = $('#post-88 .bookings .icon-close');
    swissForm.load(root+'/wp-content/themes/PL14-Base/inc/bookings-swiss.php');  

    $("#post-88 .button-book").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swissContainer.addClass('show');
    });
    swissClose.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swissContainer.removeClass('show');
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried flip-flopping e.preventDefault() and swiss.removeClass()?

Also, if it's jumping to the top of the page, it would seem that preventDefault() is doing what you want either. Replace that with return false.

```
$("#post-88 .icon-close").click(function(e) {
    swiss.removeClass('show');
    return false;
});
```

Are you showing any errors in your console? Would be my next question to you.

Comment: No errors in console, which really doesn't help. I'll try return false, but i had previously tried that (with preventDefault). I'll try it on it's own